# Dense Subset of $[0,1]^n$ might have Lebesgue Measure 0

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Good day, I have been working on a problem and one part of it just seems to get over my head.

> We are given that $\lambda^n$ is the Lebesgue measure on $\Bbb R^n$ and $E$ is a Lebesgue Measurable set
>
> Show that a dense subset of $[0, 1]^n$ might have Lebesgue measure 0

I know that a subset $A \subset [0, 1]^n $ is dense iff $\forall x \in [0, 1]^n , \forall \delta>0 \ \exists b \in A$ such that

$\vert b-x \vert < \delta$

And I have found some other question on the site that talked about considering the intersection of $\Bbb Q^n \cap [0, 1]^n$ with the Cantor set. But I did not quite understand what those were hinting at.

Comment: $\Bbb Q^n \cap [0, 1]^n$ is dense and is of Lebesgue measure $0$ (because it's countable). You don't need to intersect this with the cantor set.

Comment: Would it be worth formalising that $\Bbb Q^n$ is indeed countable?

Comment: You should ask that your teacher. It follows from the fact that a product of two countable sets is countable.

Comment: If by "formalising" you mean "proving", that would be a different question in elementary set theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your specific question should be answered by considering the set $\mathbb{Q}^n\cap [0,1]^n$, this is countable, and hence both measurable and has Lebesgue measure $0$. In the general case second countability of $\mathbb{R}^n$ should hand you the solution, however this might prove tricky, since measurable sets can look quite ugly (for instance $\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}$).

Comment: I'm not sure if this is simpler (depends on what the OP can use), but the union over $q \in \mathbb Q$ of the sets $\{q\} \times [0,1]^{n-1}$ might be easier to work with.